# is it possible to define the minimal deployment target version of Pods component

Tags: ios, flutter

I have a flutter project which using some external dependencies. I am facing a problem that some dependencies need a higher of deployment version. I found when I change the deployment version info like this:

[image]

the Xcode could not remember this change, when I open the project info the next time. The last change was lost. So I have to change it to a higher version again. The more serious problem is I could not build the project in a CI environment. So I was wonder is it possible to define a monimal deployment info version of all targets dependencies. I have already tried this way:

[image]

seems did not work as expect. the targets dependencies still use a lower version(10.0) of deployment. what should I do to define the minimal deployment target version for all the target dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found there was a pod post install script that modify the version every time. This is the script:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

just change the target version to 11.0 would fix this problem.